# Convert std::string with a binary sequence of bytes into a std::wstring with character set from current locale

Tags: c++, iostream, string-conversion, widestring, codecvt

At the moment I read the same file twice, because I need two different representations: (a) a raw byte sequence without any conversion, (b) a text representation with bytes being converted into the current execution character set. Basically, the code looks like that:

```
using namespace std;
const char* fileName = "test.txt";

// Part 1: Read the file unmodified byte-per-byte
string binContent;
ifstream file1( fileName, ifstream::binary );
while( true ) {
    char c;
    file1.get( c );
    if( !file1.good() ) break;
    binContent.push_back( c );
}

// Part 2: Read the file and convert the character code according to the
// current locale from external character set to execution character set
wstring textContent;
wifstream file2( fileName );
wifstream.imbue( locale("") );
while( true ) {
    wchar_t c;
    file2 >> c;
    if( !file2.good() ) break;
    textContent.push_back( c );
}
```

Obviously, the code reads the same file twice. I would like to avoid this and directly convert `binaryContent` to `textContent` in memory.

Please note that this is more than just a plain `char` to `wchar_t` conversion, because it also might involve a true character conversion if the character encoding of the current locale `locale("")` differs from the executation character encoding. Such a conversion might although be necessary, even if `textContent` was a narrow character string, too.

In the example above, the magic of character conversion within part 2 happens in `template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits> bool basic_filebuf<_CharT, _Traits >::_M_convert_to_external( _CharT* __ibuf, streamsize __ilen )` in `fstream.tcc` and involves using the `codecvt` facet of the locale.

I was hoping for a way to construct a `wistringstream` object from the `binContent` object instead of a `wifsteam` and then imbuing the `wistringstream` with the proper locale. But this does not seem to work, because all constructors of `wistringstream` already expect wide character nor does `wistringstream` seem to implement the conversion logic of `wifstream`.

Is there any better way (i.e. more concise and less error-prone) way than using `codecvt` manually?